# "unlimitedStorage" permission to a <webview> inside a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, webview, storage, google-chrome-app

I have a webview inside a Chrome Packaged App and the app has permissions for storage and unlimitedStorage. When I ask for the available storage space from the app It says 8 GB (that It is the whole space available in the device) but when I do it from the web app that the webview loads It says 600 MB aprox.

How can I do to set unlimitedStorage space to the webview?

Comment: AFAIK Chrome limits its *actual* usage to 10% of the available space.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a way to disable that restriction?