# PersistentStorage permission to a <webview> inside a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app, persistent-storage

My question is related to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165546) that wasn't completely answered for my specific case.

To be more specific, Can a webview web app get permission to use PersistentStorage? My experience indicates that this is not possible.

When I ask for storage space from the chrome app using navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota, it returns 8 GB. When the web app, that the webview loads, calls navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota it returns 0 and I get no indication that a permission request was made.

My manifest includes "permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "webview" ]

I use this listener/handler in my chrome app.

```
webview = document.querySelector('webview');
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', handlePermissionRequest);
function handlePermissionRequest(event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    event.request.allow();
    console.log('Requesting ' + event.permission + ' permission.');
}
```

The body of the previous question did not mention what kind of storage was being requested. My web app wants PersistentStorage for offline use.

Past discussion mentions a permission "filesystem" that no longer is supported in the manifest. ("fileSystem" is but that is another kind of storage)

I don't want to recode the web app unless I can document for my boss that navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota is not possible from within a chrome app webview.

Comment: Chromium source code says [unique origins can't store data persistently](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/quota/deprecated_storage_quota.cc?l=190&rcl=352667fc30715ae5db67f483d3bec8e194fda8b3) - does it apply to your case? Also check https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the effort but I don't think it applies to my case which is specific to <webview> content. But I will review it more.

Comment: @wOxxOm Your direction IS helpful because I did more experimentation and found that it is not a page's status as <webview> content that causes the problem.  I can get persistent storage if the webview page is an app page rather than a web page (cross-origin).  So any solution will be in finding a way to circumvent the same-origin policy (not likely.)  Thanks again.